# Log user out of multiple IdentityServer clients

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a project that uses IdentityServer4

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

We have 3 domains: `auth`, `admin` and `www`

IdentityServer runs on `auth` and the other two are ‘clients’.

- `www` uses the Hybrid flow (cookies)
- `admin` uses the Implicit flow (it is a SPA, using oidc-client)

We have a single login page hosted on `auth`. When the user logs in they are taken to `www`. Some users are allowed to access `admin` and they will see a link in the navigation.

After you login, when you access the admin you can see the authentication happen automatically and return to the callback URL. This all works fine.

However if I logout from the `admin` I can still access the `www`, and vice versa. Ideally we would like the logout to log the user out of both clients at once.

Is this possible?

---

**Note:** I'm the front end developer on this project, so the guy who actually implemented it may provide additional details in comments below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

The docs for idsrv4 are not done yet - but it works pretty much like this

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout.html

This is an implementation of the signout spec for JS
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

..and for web apps
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html

you need to read those documents to understand the mechanisms

Comment: Thanks Dominick. Is the iframe check_session_iframe postMessage approach something that is supported by oidc-client-js do you know?

Comment: I've added an issue here: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/67

Comment: should this work even though I'm checking the status of a different client's session?